# HTML5 medical image review app

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I know very little HTML, but I want to write an
HTML5 web app to review medical images. The app
would pull jpeg images from a server, and display them
in 2x2 layout, and allow user to adjust brightness/contrast
on image. Is there an existing open source app out there that
I could use as a template to get started?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

Image processing with canvas is not too hard, though in my limited experience so far it's nice if you can require certain browsers (e.g. latest Chrome) to ensure reasonable speed.

If you're mostly interested in brightness/contrast, you'll probably want an RGB<->HSL conversion function. I might be able to assist further if needed. Out of curiosity, what's the context for this app?